# How to use multiple futures in case of failure as well

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have an actor with two Messages first responsible for inserting data in mongoDB and the second actor is responsible for inserting data in elasticsearch ,InserInMongo and InserInES namely 
there will be a case when mongodb insert operation fails or ES insert operation fails due to some exception and i am doing something like this

```
try {
        val mongoFuture: Future[Boolean] = ask(artGroupPersistenceActor, PersistArtGroupInMongo(artGroup)).mapTo[Boolean]
        val esFuture: Future[Boolean] = ask(artGroupPersistenceActor, PersistArtGroupInES(artGroup)).mapTo[Boolean]
        val resultMongo = Await.result(mongoFuture, timeout.duration)
        log.debug("store: Record Inserted inserted in mongoDB  {}", resultMongo)
        val resultES = Await.result(esFuture, timeout.duration)
        log.debug("store: Record Inserted in ES  {}", resultES)
}
catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          log.error("store:While inserting an artgroup Exception in artGroupPersistenceActor  actor", e)
          throw e
      }
```

here i want if mongoFuture is failed then i catch its exception and it should proceed with esFuture

or if both future failed i get both exception how can i archive this scenario ?

Comment: Do you need `esFuture` to execute if `mongoFuture` succeeds?

Comment: yes i need it.......

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
    for {
        x <- Future.successful {
            try {
                code here...
            } catch {
                case _: Exception => 
                    println("Error Inserting In Mongo ")
                    false
            }
        }
        y <- Future.successful {
            try {
                code here...
                    // throw new IllegalStateException("Exception thrown")
            } catch {
                case _: IllegalStateException => 
                    println("Error Inserting In ES ")
                    false
            }
        }

    } yield(x, y)
```

Now you can manipulate if error occurred while doing the process.. Good luck.

Comment: What goes in "code here..."? if it's a future, then the try-catch won't catch the exception since the code is happening on a different thread. Also, `Future.successful` is not really accomplishing anything... just extra wrapping that now necessitates a for comprehension where none was needed before.

Comment: `.successful` is not necessary but that method constructs an already completed Future with the specified result, so I just assume. Even the process happen on different thread but he said that "If mongoFuture is failed then i catch its exception and it should proceed with esFuture".

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `recover`, which will handle any matching throwable that the original Future contains:

```
    val mongoFuture = ask(artGroupPersistenceActor, PersistArtGroupInMongo(artGroup))
        .mapTo[Boolean]
        .recover {
          case e =>
            println("error in mongo: " + e)
            false
        }

      val esFuture = ask(artGroupPersistenceActor, PersistArtGroupInES(artGroup))
        .mapTo[Boolean]
        .recover {
          case e =>
            println("error in ES: " + e)
            false
        }

      val f = Future.sequence(List(mongoFuture, esFuture))
      val result: Seq[Boolean] = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)

      println(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to log the exceptions, just do this with each one:

```
mongoFuture.failed.foreach {ex => logger.error("Mongo error", ex)}
```

Answer (score 0):

it better to use `map` and `recover` instead of `Await.result`

```scala
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.duration._

implicit val timeout : akka.util.Timeout = 20.seconds

for{
  mongoResult <- (artGroupPersistenceActor ? PersistArtGroupInMongo(artGroup)).mapTo[Boolean]
  .recover{ 
    case _ => 
      log.error("mongodb error") 
      false
    }
  elasticResult <- (artGroupPersistenceActor ? PersistArtGroupInES(artGroup)).mapTo[Boolean]
  .recover{ 
    case _ => 
      log.error("elastic error") 
      false
    }
} yield {
  (mongoResult, elasticResult)
}
```